# how to make a non-partition field of a table mandatory in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra-2.0

How do I make a non-partition field of the table mandatory in Cassandra? I can't find anything in the documentation unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any NULL or NOT NULL constraints as you'd find in a relational database. The only requirement is to have a primary key.